# How to have a LINQ Query - Distinct()

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, visual-c++

After a gap, again I entered to Visual C++ 2010. Now my intention is to prepare a LINQ Query to select a distinct value from a datatable

In C# My Query

```
var ProjLnkQry = (from P in MyGlobalData.ProjectTbl.AsEnumerable() select P["proj_name"]).Distinct().ToList();
```

The above query I try to convert it into VIsual C++

```
auto DistDepQry=(from v1 in MyGlobalData::ProjectTbl::AsEnumaerable() select v1["depart_name"])->Distinct()->ToList();
```

But not succeeded....Thanks for the ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String^ SelectFn(Task^ i) { return i->Name; }

void Fn()
{
    List<Task^>^ data = GetData();

    List<String^>^ query = Enumerable::ToList(
        Enumerable::Distinct(
            Enumerable::Select(
                Enumerable::AsEnumerable(data),
                gcnew Func<Task^, String^>(&SelectFn)
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Obviously you should change types, to match your query, but I hope that would be enough for start.